# preg_match doesn't detect Arabic characters

Tags: php, regex

This code is not working:

```
$text = 'بيتر' // Arabic
if (preg_match('^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669 ]+$', $text))
    echo "Text has some arabic/hebrew characters.";
else
    echo "Text doesnt have arabic/hebrew characters.";
```

result:

```
Text doesnt have arabic/hebrew characters.
```

Also 
`\p{Arabic}` is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the more up voted answers do not seem to work on my own PHP, your own version is the same.

I found this regex to work on your example text:

```
if (preg_match("/[א-ת]/", $text))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use the `//u` *Unicode* regex flag to match those characters.

You never want to put Unicode literal text inside a class if it could be that
the code source can be generated in UTF-16, that would open the possibility
of surrogates inside classes, which is a no no.

When you use the Unicode regex flag, it will convert the target string into 
a Unicode string because both regex and target must be in the same mode.

Really all you need to find is the first Arabic or Hebrew letter, so your
regex can use the Script property syntax `\p{}`, or the Unicode character syntax `\x{}` as a range.

The two ways are:

```
if (preg_match( '/[\p{Arabic}\p{Hebrew}]/u', $text))
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c6eb694ae6a7e4d1e8c4f2ead4777f9d19f37105

or

```
if (preg_match('/[\x{591}-\x{5C7}\x{5D0}-\x{5EA}\x{5F0}-\x{5F4}\x{600}-\x{604}\x{606}-\x{60B}\x{60D}-\x{61A}\x{61E}\x{620}-\x{63F}\x{641}-\x{64A}\x{656}-\x{66F}\x{671}-\x{6DC}\x{6DE}-\x{6FF}\x{750}-\x{77F}\x{8A0}-\x{8B4}\x{8B6}-\x{8BD}\x{8D4}-\x{8E1}\x{8E3}-\x{8FF}\x{FB1D}-\x{FB36}\x{FB38}-\x{FB3C}\x{FB3E}\x{FB40}-\x{FB41}\x{FB43}-\x{FB44}\x{FB46}-\x{FBC1}\x{FBD3}-\x{FD3D}\x{FD50}-\x{FD8F}\x{FD92}-\x{FDC7}\x{FDF0}-\x{FDFD}\x{FE70}-\x{FE74}\x{FE76}-\x{FEFC}\x{10E60}-\x{10E7E}\x{1EE00}-\x{1EE03}\x{1EE05}-\x{1EE1F}\x{1EE21}-\x{1EE22}\x{1EE24}\x{1EE27}\x{1EE29}-\x{1EE32}\x{1EE34}-\x{1EE37}\x{1EE39}\x{1EE3B}\x{1EE42}\x{1EE47}\x{1EE49}\x{1EE4B}\x{1EE4D}-\x{1EE4F}\x{1EE51}-\x{1EE52}\x{1EE54}\x{1EE57}\x{1EE59}\x{1EE5B}\x{1EE5D}\x{1EE5F}\x{1EE61}-\x{1EE62}\x{1EE64}\x{1EE67}-\x{1EE6A}\x{1EE6C}-\x{1EE72}\x{1EE74}-\x{1EE77}\x{1EE79}-\x{1EE7C}\x{1EE7E}\x{1EE80}-\x{1EE89}\x{1EE8B}-\x{1EE9B}\x{1EEA1}-\x{1EEA3}\x{1EEA5}-\x{1EEA9}\x{1EEAB}-\x{1EEBB}\x{1EEF0}-\x{1EEF1}]/u', $text))
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7eb3834f1d25a5f53261f016a7b849db9aa5ac5